# Which test statistic to use to test for cross-sectional dependence in panel data (R, plm)?

Tags: panel-data, cross-correlation, plm

I would like to test for cross-sectionally dependent residuals in my panelmodel (pooled). I found `pcdtest()` in *plm* package and tried `pcdtest(mod, test="cd")`, which yielded p = 0.03845. However, `pcdtest(mod, test="lm")` gave me p = 0.2266.

According to *plm* documentation `test="cd"` uses Pesaran's CD statistic, while `test="lm"` uses Breusch/Pagan's LM statistic.

What is the difference between `test="lm"` and `test="cd"`, in practical terms?

Answer (score 2):

From Baltagi (2005, 3rd edition), p. 247:

> Monte Carlo experiments show that the standard Breusch–Pagan LM test
>   performs badly for N > T panels, whereas Pesaran’s CD test performs well
>   even for small T and large N.